# Multiprocess pool.starmap can't pickle arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, closures

I'm having trouble running running a pool starmap command on a function shown in the code below. I receive the error `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Class_Name.Function_Outer.<locals>.Function_inner.<locals>.Function_Inner2'`

Note it seems to be the `starmap` command itself causing the issue. I'm not sure if my inputs are wrong or what - normally it works for me.

Here is the code that seems to be causing the problem

```
from fabric import connection
import multiprocessing as mp

paths = ["/path/to/filename.txt", "/path/to/filename2.txt"]
pi_addresses = ["192.168.2.100", "192.168.2.101"]
```

...

```
def Inner_make_files(self, pi_addresses, paths):      

    #This list just creates a list of Raspberry Pis to SSH into with the fabric module
    pi_list = [connection.Connection(x, port=22, user="pi",
                connect_kwargs={"password" : “Raspberry”}) for x in self.pi_addresses]
    barrier = mp.Barrier(len(self.pi_list))

    def Inner2_create_file(self, pi, path):
        nonlocal barrier
        barrier.wait()
        pi.run(“raspistill -o {}”.format(path))  #Creates a new photo on the Pis
        pi.get(path, path) #Retrieves new file that was made

    print(paths)
    print(pi_list)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = len(pi_list))
    pool.starmap(Inner2_create_file, zip(pi_list, paths))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The `print` statements output two lists, one of the photos and one of the connections. Both lists are two items long.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You will need to define `Inner2_create_file` outside of `Inner_make_files` in order for `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap` to work.

Comment: Yep that was the issue. Thanks!